# show data on a JTextArea instead of console

Tags: java, swing, console, system, jtextarea

I want to have a JTextArea that can completely work instead of a **console** but I don't know how to do this!

Thank you

Comment: Most likely because your question does not show any effort to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*The solution to the problem is to redirect `System.{in,out,err}` to a `JTextArea`.*

---

- Starting with `System.out` it's pretty straight forward to to redirect it to your `JTextArea` component using [`System.setOut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) method. In the example below I've done this using pipes and `SwingWorker` but that is all fancy stuff to actually get the output simpler to the swing component.
- Emulating `System.in` is simular, you need to redirect your keystrokes to the the `System.in` using [`System.setIn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn%28java.io.InputStream%29). Again, in the example below, I've used pipes to get a nicer interface. I also buffer the line (just like a "normal" console would do) till you hit enter. *(Note that for example arrow keys will not work but it shouldn't be to much work to get it also to be handled/ignored.)*

---

The text in the screenshot below was produced by a number of calls to the "normal" `System.out.print..` method and then waiting for input on `System.in` using a `Scanner`:

[image: screenshot]

```
public static JTextArea console(final InputStream out, final PrintWriter in) {
    final JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

    // handle "System.out"
    new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
        @Override protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(out);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) publish(s.nextLine() + "\n");
            return null;
        }
        @Override protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String line : chunks) area.append(line);
        }
    }.execute();

    // handle "System.in"
    area.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        private StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
        @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            if (c == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                in.println(line);
                line.setLength(0); 
            } else if (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) { 
                line.setLength(line.length() - 1); 
            } else if (!Character.isISOControl(c)) {
                line.append(e.getKeyChar());
            }
        }
    });

    return area;
}
```

And the example `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // 1. create the pipes
    PipedInputStream inPipe = new PipedInputStream();
    PipedInputStream outPipe = new PipedInputStream();

    // 2. set the System.in and System.out streams
    System.setIn(inPipe);
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new PipedOutputStream(outPipe), true));

    PrintWriter inWriter = new PrintWriter(new PipedOutputStream(inPipe), true);

    // 3. create the gui 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("\"Console\"");
    frame.add(console(outPipe, inWriter));
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // 4. write some output (to JTextArea)
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    System.out.println("Test");
    System.out.println("Test");
    System.out.println("Test");

    // 5. get some input (from JTextArea)
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("got from input: \"%s\"%n", s.nextLine());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Simple Java Console (Swing based)](http://www.comweb.nl/java/Console/Console.html)

Comment: I am new to java, what i do was i just simply copy the tutorial code and paste it to my java class and hope it to run. Well the code given not working that way. :)