# Getting multiple output strings trying to copy from JTextField to the console

Tags: java, swing

I am working on this program that connects to a remote server via telnet or SSH ( the user can chose which connection type), and the output is being displayed on the console (default `System.out`).

I wrote code to write out to a `JTextField` whatever was being written on to the console.

What i wanted to do next was try to make it so that the user can also INPUT their own commands through the `JTextArea` and whenever they press enter, the code they typed would get sent out.

For my own debugging purposes i wanted to print out to the console the user input first just to make sure i am sending the right data.

I have this little code snippet here..

```
// jtxt is a JTextField i defined earler in code
// and the variable J is a String.

jtxt.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (ke.getKeyChar() == ke.VK_ENTER) {

            j = jtxt.getText();
            System.out.println(j);
        }
    }
});
```

The only problem i am having is, I tested this out myself and my jtextarea had the text "admin" so `string j  = "admin"` but whenver i printed it out to the screen, it would print like a million of the word "admin". Any ideas?  BTW, theres no loop even near the addKeyListener.

Comment: This question (or a very similar one at least) was recently asked, and answered over here: [show data on a JTextArea instead of console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680318/show-data-on-a-jtextarea-instead-of-console/9680496#9680496).

Comment: The debugger is your best friend! Place a breakpoint over your println and check our what's happening - one thing is for sure, the code is always (or most usually) right.

Comment: 1) [Add an action listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29) rather than a `KeyListener` for this one.  2) Are you certain that *"a million"* is not actually 5?  3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the user is holding down the enter key for too long. Your computer is rechecking for the keyTyped() while the current key press is still happening. Change the method name from keyTyped to keyReleased. That should fix your error.