# Building a console application in Java

Tags: java, swt, console-application

I am looking towards building a console shell-like program that can run in Windows/Mac/Linux UI. I know Eclipse provides a few console implementations, but that would require an Eclipse RCP application.

Any suggestions on other light-weight existing open-source solutions for the same.

Suggestions on pure shell-consoles are welcome as well. I already have checked JShell and Jline.

**Update:**
My research has not brought any other frameworks that can be used, unless we use a Swing/SWT text area and manage it all together. I found using an Eclipse Console better as it offers more choices and some functionality already baked into it.

**Update:**
Spring Source has just released a framework called **spring-shell** to make building console shell applications easier. It forks from the **Roo** source code, and thus provides the same functionality as in **Roo**.

Comment: You can do it right on vim. write code javac it and java it then.

Comment: A GUI for a shell prompt?  Should be quite doable with plain Swing.

Comment: Check this post: [Redirect system io to `JTextField`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680318/show-data-on-a-jtextarea-instead-of-console)

Comment: @TJ- - I am looking to compile Java code in shell.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Could you point me to an example, I have never worked with Swing before.

Answer (score 0):

Jline is the only viable shell framework available for Java that works on all platforms well. There is lots of native code required for something like this to really work well. Jline does this the best as of this answer. I usually use it in concert with JSAP with great success to create custom application management shells that work in a headless server. DevOps guys go nuts for stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks - but as I mentioned targetting UI in the question and thus the choice for Eclipse console. JLine is definitely the best option for headless shells. Also, may I know the reason for down voting?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Source has just released a framework called **spring-shell** to make building console shell applications easier. It forks from the **Roo** source code, and thus provides the same functionality as in **Roo**.