# Making my own Java IDE

Tags: java, input, cmd, ide, output

I am trying to make my own Java IDE, however i am having problems getting the input from user after displaying the program itself

I have so far tried 2 ways of getting the console to appear.
Using [Create Java console inside a GUI panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342990/create-java-console-inside-a-gui-panel/343007#343007)

or using my own code of

```
void runCommand(String command)
{
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", command);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileToClass2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}

void createClass(String dir, String filename)
{
    //TODO: stop using exact java path / compile all .java in a dir
    runCommand("cd "+dir+" && \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_91\\bin\\javac\" " + filename);
}

void runClass(String dir, String filename)
{
    //TODO: allow use of packages etc
    runCommand("cd " + dir + " && java " + filename);
}
```

This above code simply gets the output of the cmd terminal, the problem both these approaches have is the lack of input say if the user wanted to do a Scanner nextLine()
Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you're creating your own IDE for learning purposes?  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000007.html

Comment: It's simply a side project to do while i have free time for fun to learn yes

Comment: Answer found here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680318/show-data-on-a-jtextarea-instead-of-console

Comment: Very good, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680318/show-data-on-a-jtextarea-instead-of-console

Comment: Picking this up again after a three year hiatus?

Comment: Realised i never marked the question as answered  even though i found an answer so selected "Answer Your Question" to post were i originally found the answer